# magento 1 how can get images URL by images name

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, url

How can I get an image URL from the image name? 
Please provide me steps and also let me where need to keep code(folder or file location) to get URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get product image by product name only. You need to load product by SKU or ID and then you can get the image details using the following code.

```
$prdId = 35;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$prdoduct = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prdId);
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();

$productImageUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $prdoduct->getImage();
$productUrl  = $product->getProductUrl();
```

Comment: Magento 1+ I know only (/skin/frontend/default/default/images/color.jpg), now just want to know where in the frontend pages this images displaying.